# Where does IntelliJ store the JDKs that it downloads on my behalf?

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, download

Recent versions of IntelliJ can download a JDK for the convenience of the user.

However, those downloaded JDKs are not appearing in the canonical place, at least not on my Mac:

```sh
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
```

So where are the downloaded JDKs being stored?

I would like to inspect them, and possibly delete some.

I have found this documentation page, [*SDKs*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html), but did not see the storage location mentioned there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

> `/Users/your_username_here/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`

## Details

You can inspect the JDKs known to IntelliJ by choosing *File > Project Structure > Platform Settings > SDKs*.

[image: Screenshot of IntelliJ's list of known SDKS with inspector for their location]

Notice how the location of the selected JDK is shown in the *JDK home path* field.

In this example, the JDK downloaded by IntelliJ was put in:

```bash
/Users/your_username_here/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
```

Note that this location contrasts with the location used by some of the independent JDK installers. In my experience, those tools use the root `/Library` path, rather than in the user’s `~/Library`. That full path would be: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`.

Comment: `/Library` is the system wide installation location.  `~/Library` is for you only.

Answer (score 0):

It's changing form version to version, but can be easily inspected via:

File > Project Structure > Platform Settings | SDKs

now it's in `.jdks` subfolder in 2023 :)