# Mac install java [openjdk]: brew vs. cask vs. IntelliJ IDEA (different JDK paths)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, homebrew, homebrew-cask

Do the below **different JDK paths**, that result from installation (on Mac) with the given different methods (possibly by any defaults they have), **reflect or imply any differences (in functionality, access, configuration, or intended use of the JDK)** across the different install mechanisms?

- Even though below details involve openjdk [specifically], my broader intent is not vendor-specific to openjdk.
- (One [tangential] example of a source of my curiosity, is that [Mac default] System Python [should not](https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac) be used by user - instead, user development [should only](https://realpython.com/lessons/why-not-system-python/) be done with user-installed Python; and [fwiw] those two different Python installs have separate installed paths..)

(I hope I have all of the details correct below... :)

1. `brew install java`

   - (using [just] `homebrew`)
   - [installs at](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-install-java-on-mac-osx/#homebrew-install-latest-java-on-macos) `/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/`

     - (symbolic link created at `/usr/local/opt/openjdk`)
2. `brew install --cask adoptopenjdk`

   - (using `homebrew-cask`)
   - [installs at](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48275645/1357094) `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-<version number>.jdk/`
3. installing in/with `IntelliJ IDEA`

   - [installs at](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71669455/1357094) `~/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-<version number>.jdk/`

     - (note [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71669393/where-does-intellij-store-the-jdks-that-it-downloads-on-my-behalf#comment127711836_71669455) here [compared to 2^] being under user-home `~`, not root `/`)

I think I know at least the below differences; but are there other relevant differences?

- 2 vs 3 [differ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71669393/where-does-intellij-store-the-jdks-that-it-downloads-on-my-behalf#comment127711836_71669455) on 3 being accessible only to the given `~` *current* user, while I think 2 is available [system-wide] to *all* users

  - I think same difference on 1 vs 3?
- 1 has the (noted^) symbolic link detail